# Get contents of every dataframe cell that matches a keyword

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the correct way to search every cell of a dataframe and see if that cell contains a value that is in a list of keywords?  The example below is short... the real datafarame could have any number of columns/rows and contain nulls. I know it's not correct, but a starting point is here:

```
import pandas as pd

myKeywords = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
myData = [['apple',10],['coconut',12],['donut',13],['I love apples',13]]
myDf = pd.DataFrame(myData,columns=['colOne','colN'],dtype=float)
print myDf

def findAll(keywordList, df):
  return df[(df.values.ravel() in keywordList).reshape(df.shape).any(1)]

result = findAll(myKeys, myDf)
print result
```

# I would expect it to only print the values 'apple' and 'I love apples'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `df.values.ravel().astype(str)` to get all the values from all the cells as a regular list, then I filter it based on `any` to see if a keyword is a substring of some value.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

myKeywords = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
myData = [['apple',10],['coconut',12],['donut',13],['I love apples',13]]
myDf = pd.DataFrame(myData,columns=['colOne','colN'],dtype=float)

def findAll(keywordList, df):
    return [value for value in df.values.ravel().astype(str) if any(word in value for word in keywordList)]

result = findAll(myKeywords, myDf)
print(result)
```

Output:

> ['apple', 'I love apples']

Comment: Awesome! How do i convert that to a flat array that only has the cell results, regardless of what column it was found in? In this case only apple and i love apples?

Comment: Also, how do i do this for any number of cols? I dont want to hardcode col names. Thanks!

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 oh, if all you want is all the values, from any cell, without needing to know where it came from, then you had the right idea with `ravel` in your original code. edited my answer.